# IntelliJ IDEA is not showing scala file option in play project

Tags: playframework-2.0, scala-2.10, intellij-14

I have created play project using typesafe activator 1.2.12 and converted into IntelliJ IDEA using idea command.

Then I have imported into IntelliJ IDEA.

I have edited routes file.

Then I tried to create scala file in controllers directory by right clicking but it is not showing any options for scala file creation.

Could anybodyhelp me on this issue.

Comment: Also I am getting error
cannot load facet scala Details.

Comment: Have you installed the Scala plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same issue with IntelliJ 14

File -> Project Structure -> Modules and, under the module named after the project, deleted the "Scala" facet with the question mark beside it.

I then clicked the + sign and added Scala.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this by following the below steps.

1. File -> Project Structure or press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S (shortcut to open Project Structure)
2. In Project Settings -> Select Modules
3. Click on '+' symbol and select 'New Module'
4. Select 'Scala'
5. Click'Next' and 'Finish'
6. Select 'File' -> 'Scala Class'